# Using EventHub RBAC feature to publish events

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am writing a publisher service that wants to publish events to a client event hub. Is it correct that by using RBAC, I can achieve without having to worry about SAS keys? If so, is there any sample code I can look at.

I have been looking at the github samples at https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Rbac/EventHubsSenderReceiverRbac/ but they seem to be using individual user accounts for RBAC.